# Select inputs of a tr

Tags: jquery, html-table

How to select only the inputs of a table row? I mean all the inputs of each row that is clicked.

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th><input type="text" name="num" value="num"/></th>   
    <th><input type="text" name="a" value="a"/></th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td> <input type="text" name="num" value=""/> </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="a" value=""/></td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

CSS:

```
.highlight { background-color: blue; }
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
    $("tr input").click(function(){     
        $("tr input").toggleClass("highlight").siblings().removeClass("highlight"); 
    })      
})
```

- I have this here to test:http://jsfiddle.net/yg4n6/
- I have here an example of the effect that I am looking for. This works well but this is only a table. I am trying to do the same with inputs inside the table: http://jsfiddle.net/yg4n6/5/

Comment: It is working for me on Chrome

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What does not work as expected? How should it work? I guess you just have forgotten the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the `this` parent and search for .highlight to remove existent.
Than apply .highlight to `this` -> TR -> inputs

http://jsfiddle.net/yg4n6/2/

```
$("tr input").click(function(){      
     $(this).closest('table').find('.highlight').removeClass("highlight");
     $(this).closest('tr').find('input').toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

You can do also:

```
$("tr").click(function( e ){          
    if(e.target.tagName=='INPUT'){
       var $this = $(e.target);
       $this.closest('table').find('.highlight').removeClass("highlight");
       $this.closest('tr').find('input').toggleClass("highlight");
    }
});
```

Comment: This works well!. Thank you. I don't understand the use of closest in this case. Can you explain, please?

Comment: @Nrc http://api.jquery.com/closest/ it's to jump over your `TH`s and `TD`s so we can traverse back the tree using `.find()` to find the `.highlight`

Comment: I understand the need of .closest in the first line. But in the second line wouldn't be this enough?: $(this).toggleClass("highlight");

Comment: @Nrc, no, cause `$(this)` is only one element, you need a collection of elements, by going back the tree finding the `TR` and creating a collection of all `inputs` using `.find()` will do the job.